# no persistence with cookies and headers with requests.session

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, persistence

I have an issue using `requests` package from `Python`, I'm sending two requests, one `POST` and one `GET` using the same URL domain. I realized that my headers and cookies are not persistent.

Basically, I'm doing it that way:

```
cookies = get_very_long_and_complex_cookies()
response = session.post(url,
                        headers = headers,
                        cookies = cookies,
                        files   = multipart_form_data)
[...]
response = session.get(url)
```

The first request is fine but the second one, do not contain the cookies and headers set for the first request. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I'm answering my own question for history.

So session object contain a `cookies` attribute. It can be used to saved the cookie inside a session.

```
cookies = get_it_from_somewhere()
for n, v in cookies.items():
    session.cookies.set(n, v)
```